# AvalonEdit copy/paste as text

Tags: ironpython, avalonedit, clipboarddata

I'm using AvalonEdit as editor and output window for IronPython in a wpf application. At runtime I often have to copy/paste data from the output window (AvalonEdit) to Excel for further processing. Unfortunately AvalonEdit copies the data as HTML/Unicode/Text to the clipboard. Excel chooses to paste it as HTML so all data end up as text and not as numbers. 
I can of course import it correctly with "Paste Special" and choosing "Text" but it would be less confusing and much quicker to users if they could simply import with CTRL V.

**Question is**: Is there a possibility to limit the formats AvalonEdit exports to the clipboard? For this application I'd prefer to have "TEXT" only on the clipboard.